# Scroll between view without React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The components in my React App are rendered by their location in the index like a stepper.

Full example on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-otwg1l?file=src/Comp3.jsx

**App.js**

```
const steps = [
    {
      id: 'location',
      component: StepLocation,
    },
    {
      id: 'questions',
      component: StepQuestions,
    },
    {
      id: 'appointment',
      component: StepDate,
    },
]

       return (
         <Step steps={steps} />
       )
// remaning code
```

`steps` are passed as props into my main Stepper component
**Step.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useStep } from 'react-hooks-helper';

const Step = ({ steps = {} }) => {
  const { step, navigation, index } = useStep({ initialStep: 0, steps });
  const { id } = step;
  const props = { navigation, index };

  const Component = steps.find((innerStep) => innerStep.id === id).component;
  return <Component {...props} steps={steps} />;
};

export default Step;
```

The stepper works but when I navigate between steps, I have to scroll back to the top of the page. I know that I will need create a scroll to top function or a CSS transition, but since my application does not use react-router to navigate between views, how can I add this function / where do I put it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a scroll to top button with vanilla JS. This can be easily integrated into your component. Add it in a useEffect whit step as index to get it to work everytime you switch steps

See this for the scroll to top option: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you have a component to handle the current step. In that case you can handle the scroll position in `useEffect` block every time the selected step changes:

```
const [step, setStep] = useEffect(value);

useEffect(()=> {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
}, [step]);
```